# Trying to create folders from Excel but folders are not showing up in the selected location as I type, code is not running as showing compile error

Tags: excel

[code in VBA editor is not running as it shows compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7yPK.png)

Comment: Please put your code in a code block rather than posting an image (see help). It's fine to state your error and the line that causes it in the text of our question

Comment: You've got a bunch of code outside a subroutine (missing a starting `Sub foo()`)

Comment: Thanks bigBen  n Bugdrown.

Answer (score 0):

`SUB` Missing Start Position PLease See Thee Top Bottom